# Define a constant array of struct known at compilation-time

Tags: common-lisp

In my program I have constant strings, the values are known at compilation time. For each offset there are currently 2 associated strings. I first wrote the following code:

```
(eval-when (:compile-toplevel :load-toplevel :execute) ;; BLOCK-1
  (defstruct test-struct
    str-1
    str-2))

(eval-when (:compile-toplevel) ;; BLOCK-2

  (defparameter +GLOBAL-VECTOR-CONSTANT+ nil) ;; ITEM-1

  (let ((vector (make-array 10
                            :initial-element (make-test-struct)
                            :element-type    'test-struct)))
    (setf (test-struct-str-1 (aref vector 0)) "test-0-1")
    (setf (test-struct-str-2 (aref vector 0)) "test-0-2")

    (setf +GLOBAL-VECTOR-CONSTANT+ vector)))

(format t "[~A]~%" (test-struct-str-1 (elt +GLOBAL-VECTOR-CONSTANT+ 0)))
(format t "[~A]~%" (test-struct-str-2 (elt +GLOBAL-VECTOR-CONSTANT+ 0)))
```

This seems to work as it returns the following:

```
[test-2-1]
[test-2-2]
```

In `BLOCK-1` the `struct` containing the data is defined, for `compile-time`, `load-time` and `execute-time`. In `BLOCK-2`, the code which create a vector and sets the values is executed, at `compile-time`.

But I have the following concerns:

- This code seems unnecessary verbose
- The strings are stored in a `structure`
- I need to manually set the `offset` of each values (`(aref vector 0)`, `(aref vector 1)`, etc).
- When I set `ITEM-1` inside `BLOCK-1` instead of `BLOCK-2` I get an error in `SBCL` which I don't understand

What is the idiomatic way to define complex constants in `Common Lisp`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really clear what you want to do from your question.

First important note: your code is seriously broken.  It's broken because you define `+global-vector-constant+` only at compile time but refer to it later than that.  If you compile this file and then load that compiled file into a cold image you will get errors.

It is *absolutely critical* when dealing with things like this to make sure that your code will compile in a cold Lisp.  One of the classic problems with resident environments (which CL isn't really, compared to the way Interlisp-D was for instance) is to end up with systems which you can't cold build: I'm pretty sure I worked for several years with an Interlisp-D sysout that no-one knew how to cold build any more.

If what you want is an object (an array, for instance) whose initial value is computed at compile time and then treated as a literal, then the answer to that is, in general, a macro: macros are exactly functions which do their work at compile time, and so a macro can expand to a literal.  In addition it must be the case that the object you want to be a literal is *externalizable* (which means 'can be dumped in compiled files') and anything involved in it is known about at compile time.  Instances of some classes are externalizable by default, those of some other classes can be made externalizable by user code, and some are not externalizable at all (for instance functions).

In quite a lot of simple cases, like the one you gave, if I understand it, you don't really need a macro, and in fact you can almost always get away without one, although it may make your code easier to understand if you do use one.

Here is a simple case: many arrays are externalizable if their elements are

```
(defparameter *my-strings*
  #(("0-l" . "0-r")
    ("1-l" . "1-r")))
```

This means that `*my-strings*` will be bound to a literal array of conses of strings.

A more interesting case is when the elements are, for instance structures. Well, structures are also externalizable, so we can do that.  And in fact it's quite possible, still, to avoid a macro, although it now becomes a bit noisy.

```
(eval-when (:compile-toplevel :load-toplevel :execute)
  (defstruct foo
    l
    r))

(defparameter *my-strings*
  #(#s(foo :l "0-l" :r "0-r")
    #s(foo :l "1-l" :r "1-r")))
```

Note that the following *won't* work:

```
(defstruct foo
  l
  r)

(defparameter *my-strings*
  #(#s(foo :l "0-l" :r "0-r")
    #s(foo :l "1-l" :r "1-r")))
```

It won't work because, at compile time, you are trying to externalize instances of a structure which is not yet defined (but it probably *will* work if the Lisp is not cold, and you might even be able to reload the compiled file you made that way).  Again, in this case you can avoid the `eval-when` in a larger system by ensuring that the file which defines the `foo` structure is compiled and loaded before the file with the `defparameter` is loaded.

And even in more complex cases you can escape using a macro.  For instance for many sorts of objects which are normally not externalizable you can teach the system how to externalize them, and then splice the object in as a literal using `#.`:

```
(eval-when (:compile-toplevel :load-toplevel :execute)
  ;; Again, this would be in its own file in a bigger system
  (defclass string-table-wrapper ()
    ((strings)
     (nstrings :initform 0)))

  (defmethod initialize-instance :after ((w string-table-wrapper)
                                         &key (strings '()))
    (let ((l (length strings)))
      (when l
        (with-slots ((s strings) (n nstrings)) w
          (setf s (make-array l :initial-contents strings)
                n l)))))

  (defmethod make-load-form ((w string-table-wrapper) &optional environment)
    (make-load-form-saving-slots w :slot-names '(strings nstrings)
                                 :environment environment))
  )                                     ;eval-when

(defgeneric get-string (from n)
  (:method ((from string-table-wrapper) (n fixnum))
   (with-slots (strings nstrings) from
     (assert (< -1 n nstrings )
         (n)
       "bad index")
     (aref strings n))))

(defparameter *my-strings*
  #.(make-instance 'string-table-wrapper
                   :strings '("foo" "bar")))
```

Note that, of course, although the value of `*my-strings*` is a literal, code ran to reconstruct this object at load-time.  But that is always the case: it's just that in this case you had to define what code needed to run.  Instead of using `make-load-form-saving-slots` you could have done this yourself, for instance by something like this:

```
(defmethod make-load-form ((w string-table-wrapper) &optional environment)
   (declare (ignore environment))
   (if (slot-boundp w 'strings)
       (values
        `(make-instance ',(class-of w))
        `(setf (slot-value ,w 'strings)
               ',(slot-value w 'strings)
               (slot-value ,w 'nstrings)
               ,(slot-value w 'nstrtrings)))
     `(make-instance ',(class-of w))))
```

But `make-load-form-saving-slots` is much easier.

---

Here is an example where a macro does perhaps least make reading the code easier.

Let's assume you have a function which reads an array of strings from a file, for instance this:

```
(defun file-lines->svector (file)
  ;; Needs CL-PPCRE
  (with-open-file (in file)
    (loop
       with ltw = (load-time-value
                   (create-scanner '(:alternation
                                     (:sequence
                                      :start-anchor
                                      (:greedy-repetition 1 nil
                                       :whitespace-char-class))
                                     (:sequence
                                      (:greedy-repetition 1 nil
                                       :whitespace-char-class)
                                      :end-anchor)))
                   t)
       for nlines upfrom 0
       for line = (read-line in nil)
       while line
       collect (regex-replace-all ltw line "") into lines
       finally (return (make-array nlines :initial-contents lines)))))
```

Then, if this function is available at macroexpansion time, you could write this macro:

```
(defmacro file-strings-literal (file)
  (check-type file (or string pathname) "pathname designator")
  (file-lines->svector file))
```

And now we can create a literal vector of strings:

```
(defparameter *fl* (file-strings-literal "/tmp/x"))
```

However you could perfectly well instead do this:

```
(defparameter *fl* #.(file-lines->svector "/tmp/x"))
```

Which will do the same thing, but slightly earlier (at read time, rather than at macroexpansion/compile time).  So this is gaining nothing really.

But you could also do *this*:

```
(defmacro define-stringtable (name file &optional (doc nil docp))
  `(defparameter ,name ,(file-lines->svector file)
     ,@(if docp (list doc) nil)))
```

And now your code reads like

```
(define-stringtable *st* "my-stringtable.dat")
```

And that actually is a significant improvement.

Finally note that in `file-lines->svector` that `load-time-value` is used to create the scanner exactly once, at load time, which is a related trick.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, I learnt several things from it. Could you edit your answer just to add an example for the macro usage. Is it as straight-forward as `(defmacro create-const-table () #(#s(foo :l "0-l" :r "0-r")))` and `(defparameter table (create-const-table))`? If so, then I understand what you mean, it seems absolutely unnecessary.

Comment: @Robert: I've added a case where a macro might be useful, which also demonstrates the use of `load-time-value` to do a similar trick: compute some value once which you will later use but don't want to either be in a global or computed on every call.

Comment: Thank you @ignis volens, I like your macro-based example, I think it's very clear.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your `let` code can be simplified to

```lisp
(defparameter +global-vector-constant+
  (let ((vector ...))
    ...
    vector))
```

Second, you can also do

```lisp
(defparameter +global-vector-constant+
  (make-array 10 :element-type 'test-struct :initial-content
              (cons (make-test-struct :str-1 "test-0-1" :str-2 "test-0-2")
                    (loop :repeat 9 :collect (make-test-struct)))))
```

Note that the benefit of `:element-type 'test-struct` is generally limited to code self-documentation (see [`upgraded-array-element-type`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_upgr_1.htm))

Comment: The :ELEMENT-TYPE (also in the original question) makes no sense? Wouldn't it be upgraded to T anyway? Would you keep it for documentation?

Comment: @RainerJoswig: yes, this is what my last sentence is saying - doc only.

Comment: Thank you for your answer guys, unfortunately it does not really help me, I already know about structures, let and loops. What I never understood properly in practice is actually `eval-when`. I am looking for a small and complete example of how I can define *an array of struct at compile time*. I am afraid that the code example I wrote is actually not working properly, I tried it today and it seems broken. I don't need `loop` because all my constants are set manually. I also don't know exactly if `defconstant` would work here.

Comment: Another point I want to make, this question is not a blocking point as I can always define an `initialize` function and call it at program startup. But in this case, the table will be built at run-time. I want to understand if `Common Lisp` has some mechanisms allowing the computation to be done ahead of time and provide to the program an object, containing the previously initialized table (kind of static data in C world, but coming from the execution of Lisp code at compile time).